# Algorithm to find paths in a list of scattered points

Tags: language-agnostic, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have a list of points taken from measuring a model. An important part of the analyses to be made consist on finding "candidate paths" along these points, that will further be trimmed and refined.

Below there are images showing a plot of the raw data, and a hand-made drawing of what the detected paths would look like. These paths should be continuous and approximately vertical, and the output format would be a list of lists of points (color of points is not relevand for path-finding itself):

[image]

I suppose this can be solved by brute-force, exhaustive methods, but I suppose, either, there can be some well-known algorithm for this.

I use Python, so Numpy/Scipy examples would be greatly appreciated (`scipy.spatial` sounds like the perfect candidate for that)

EDIT: a sample dataset is provided below (list of [x,y,weight] points):

```
[[ -0.7898176   -3.35201728   4.36142086]
 [  2.99221402  -3.35201728   1.11907575]
 [  6.97475149  -3.35201728   2.4320322 ]
 [ -4.82443609  -2.35201728   0.6479064 ]
 [ -1.32418909  -2.35201728   1.88004944]
 [  0.07067882  -2.35201728   1.10982834]
 [  3.09169448  -2.35201728   1.8557436 ]
 [  7.10399403  -2.35201728   2.03906224]
 [ -3.07207606  -1.35201728   0.35500973]
 [  2.63202993  -1.35201728   5.32397834]
 [  5.19884868  -1.35201728   1.63816326]
 [  7.65721835  -1.35201728   1.13843392]
 [  2.48172754  -0.35201728   6.65584512]
 [  6.0905911   -0.35201728   1.15552652]
 [  8.62497546  -0.35201728   0.30407144]
 [ -4.7300089    0.64798272   0.31481496]
 [ -3.03274093   0.64798272   0.95337568]
 [  2.19653614   0.64798272  10.3675204 ]
 [  6.20384058   0.64798272   1.42106077]
 [ -4.08636605   1.64798272   0.28875288]
 [  2.03344989   1.64798272  13.04648211]
 [ -4.11717795   2.64798272   0.39713141]
 [  1.93304283   2.64798272  10.41313242]
 [ -4.37994815   3.64798272   0.84588643]
 [  1.66081408   3.64798272  14.96380955]
 [ -4.19024027   4.64798272   0.73216113]
 [  1.60252433   4.64798272  14.72419286]
 [  6.77837359   4.64798272   0.6186005 ]
 [ -4.14362668   5.64798272   0.93673165]
 [  1.55372968   5.64798272  12.9421123 ]
 [ -4.62223541   6.64798272   0.6510101 ]
 [  1.527865     6.64798272  10.80209351]
 [  6.86820685   6.64798272   0.82550801]
 [ -4.68259732   7.64798272   0.45321369]
 [  1.36167494   7.64798272   6.45338514]
 [ -5.19205787   8.64798272   0.23935013]
 [  1.21003466   8.64798272  10.13528877]
 [  7.6689546    8.64798272   0.32421776]
 [ -5.36436818   9.64798272   0.79809416]
 [  1.26248534   9.64798272   7.67036253]
 [  7.35472418   9.64798272   0.92555691]
 [ -5.61723652  10.64798272   0.4741007 ]
 [  1.23101086  10.64798272   7.97064105]
 [ -7.83024735  11.64798272   0.47557318]
 [  1.20348982  11.64798272   8.20694816]
 [  1.14422758  12.64798272   9.26244889]
 [  9.18164464  12.64798272   0.72428381]
 [  1.0827069   13.64798272  10.08599118]
 [  6.80116007  13.64798272   0.4571425 ]
 [  9.384236    13.64798272   0.42399893]
 [  1.04053491  14.64798272  10.48370805]
 [  9.16197972  14.64798272   0.39930227]
 [ -9.85958581  15.64798272   0.39524976]
 [  0.9942501   15.64798272   8.39992264]
 [  8.07642416  15.64798272   0.61480371]
 [  9.55088151  15.64798272   0.54076473]
 [ -7.13657331  16.64798272   0.32929172]
 [  0.92606211  16.64798272   7.83597033]
 [  8.74291069  16.64798272   0.74246827]
 [ -7.20022443  17.64798272   0.52555351]
 [  0.81344517  17.64798272   6.81654834]
 [  8.52844624  17.64798272   0.70543711]
 [ -6.97465178  18.64798272   1.04527813]
 [  0.61959631  18.64798272  10.33529022]
 [  5.733054    18.64798272   1.2309691 ]
 [  8.14818453  18.64798272   1.37532423]
 [ -6.82823664  19.64798272   2.0314052 ]
 [  0.56391636  19.64798272  13.61447357]
 [  5.79971126  19.64798272   0.30148347]
 [  8.01499476  19.64798272   1.72465327]
 [ -6.78504689  20.64798272   2.88657804]
 [ -4.79580634  20.64798272   0.36201975]
 [  0.548376    20.64798272   7.8414544 ]
 [  7.62258506  20.64798272   1.52817905]
 [-10.50328534  21.64798272   0.90358671]
 [ -6.59976138  21.64798272   2.62980169]
 [ -3.71180255  21.64798272   1.27094175]
 [  0.5060743   21.64798272  11.06117677]
 [  4.51983105  21.64798272   1.74626435]
 [  7.50948795  21.64798272   3.46497629]
 [ 11.10199877  21.64798272   1.78047269]
 [-10.15444935  22.64798272   1.47486166]
 [ -6.26274479  22.64798272   4.73707852]
 [ -3.45440904  22.64798272   1.72516012]
 [  0.52759064  22.64798272  12.58470433]
 [  4.22258017  22.64798272   2.63827535]
 [  7.03480033  22.64798272   3.506412  ]
 [ 10.63560314  22.64798272   3.56076386]
 [ -5.95693623  23.64798272   2.97403863]
 [ -3.66261423  23.64798272   2.31667236]
 [  0.52051366  23.64798272  12.5526344 ]
 [  4.21083787  23.64798272   1.95794387]
 [  6.82438636  23.64798272   4.77995659]
 [ 10.18138299  23.64798272   5.21836205]
 [ -9.94629932  24.64798272   0.4074823 ]
 [ -5.74101948  24.64798272   2.60992238]
 [  0.52987226  24.64798272  10.68846987]
 [  6.29981921  24.64798272   3.56204471]
 [  9.96431168  24.64798272   2.85079129]
 [ -9.64229717  25.64798272   0.4503241 ]
 [ -5.579063    25.64798272   0.64475469]
 [  0.52053534  25.64798272  10.05046667]
 [  5.79167815  25.64798272   0.92797027]
 [ 10.05116919  25.64798272   2.52194933]
 [ -8.55286247  26.64798272   0.94447148]
 [  0.45065604  26.64798272  10.97432823]
 [  5.50068393  26.64798272   2.39645232]
 [ 10.08992273  26.64798272   2.77716257]
 [-16.62381217  27.64798272   0.2021621 ]
 [ -9.62146213  27.64798272   0.62245778]
 [ -7.66905507  27.64798272   2.84466396]
 [  0.38656111  27.64798272  10.74369366]
 [  5.76925402  27.64798272   1.13362978]
 [  9.83525197  27.64798272   1.18241147]
 [-15.64874512  28.64798272   0.18279302]
 [ -7.52932494  28.64798272   2.94012191]
 [  0.32171219  28.64798272  10.73770466]
 [  9.4062684   28.64798272   1.41714298]
 [-12.71287717  29.64798272   0.70268073]
 [ -7.59473877  29.64798272   2.16183026]
 [  0.20748772  29.64798272  12.97312987]
 [  3.92952496  29.64798272   1.54987681]
 [  9.05148017  29.64798272   2.40563748]
 [ 14.96021523  29.64798272   0.55258241]
 [-12.14428813  30.64798272   0.36365363]
 [ -7.12360666  30.64798272   2.54312163]
 [  0.40594038  30.64798272  12.64839117]
 [  4.59465757  30.64798272   1.23496581]
 [  8.54333134  30.64798272   2.18912857]
 [-10.6296531   31.64798272   1.4839259 ]
 [ -7.09532763  31.64798272   2.0113838 ]
 [  0.37037733  31.64798272  12.2071139 ]
 [  3.01253349  31.64798272   3.01591777]
 [  4.64523695  31.64798272   3.50267541]
 [  8.39369696  31.64798272   2.53195817]
 [ -7.07947026  32.64798272   1.01324147]
 [  0.39269437  32.64798272   9.67368625]
 [  8.58669997  32.64798272   1.00475646]
 [ 12.02329114  32.64798272   0.50782399]
 [-10.13060786  33.64798272   0.31475653]
 [ -7.30360407  33.64798272   0.35065243]
 [  0.49556923  33.64798272   9.66608818]
 [ -5.37822311  34.64798272   0.38727401]
 [  0.4958055   34.64798272   7.5415026 ]
 [  6.07719006  34.64798272   0.63012453]
 [ -4.64579055  35.64798272   0.39990249]
 [  0.46323666  35.64798272   4.60449213]
 [  4.72819312  35.64798272   0.98050594]
 [ -4.62418372  36.64798272   0.64160709]
 [  0.48866236  36.64798272   4.29331656]
 [  5.06493722  36.64798272   0.59888608]
 [  0.49730481  37.64798272   1.32828464]
 [ -1.31849217  38.64798272   0.70780886]
 [  1.70966455  38.64798272   0.88052135]
 [  0.06305774  39.64798272   0.47366487]
 [  2.13639356  39.64798272   0.67971461]
 [ -0.84726354  40.64798272   0.63787522]
 [  0.55723562  40.64798272   0.62855097]
 [  2.22359779  40.64798272   0.33884894]
 [  0.77309816  41.64798272   0.4605534 ]
 [  0.56144565  42.64798272   0.43678788]]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) for your points. This gives a graph where points are connected to each other.

Then you could remove all edges of this graph that either are too long or go in wrong direction.

Finally, you could find all vertices of this graph that do not form a proper chain (have more than 2 incident edges or have two incident edges with angle between them too far from 2*pi). And keep only the most appropriate edges.

Comment: +1. And you could probably use a modification of Douglas-Peucker algorithm to find out if it is really a "path"

Comment: After some thought about it, I'll use this strategy, most probably by adapting the code found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6541755/401828